# How to determine last stack space in recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, graph, graph-traversal

I'm implementing well-known depth first search by recursion. I wonder whether there may be a way to know the code within last stack space. Why I need is I don't want to put `->` character at the end of output. If possible just `'\n'` in the last step.

```
def DFS(self, vertex=None, visited=None):
    if vertex is None:
        vertex = self.root
    if visited is None:
        visited = []
        print(f"{vertex} -> ", end='')

    visited.append(vertex)
    for neighbor in self.getNeighbors(vertex):
        if neighbor not in visited:
            visited.append(neighbor)
            print(f"{neighbor} -> ", end='')
            self.DFS(neighbor, visited)
```

For example, it yields `1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 ->`

Is there anyway to do within the same method? Moreover, I could write a helper function removing the last `->` character.

@Edit:  What I've done according to @Carcigenicate's comment follows

```
return visited # last line in DFS method
-- in main --
dfs = graph.DFS()
path = " -> ".join(str(vertex) for vertex in dfs)
print(path)
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off putting the path steps into a list and just doing `",".join(steps)` at the end. Printing from inside functions should usually be avoided in most cases anyways.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, it seems an alternative way. Thanks

Comment: You should put that in an Answer, not the Question.

Comment: @Barmar there may be other alternatives.

Comment: That's fine. There are often multiple answers to the question, you decide which one is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to special-case the last vertex, special-case the first. That is, don't try to figure out when not to append the "->", just don't do it for the first vertex:

```
def DFS(self, vertex=None, visited=None):
    if vertex is None:
        vertex = self.root
    else:
        # Not the first vertex, so need to add the separator.
        print(f" ->", end='')

    if visited is None:
        visited = []

    print(f"{vertex}", end='')

    visited.append(vertex)
    for neighbor in self.getNeighbors(vertex):
        if neighbor not in visited:
            # no need to append here, because it will be done in the recursive call.
            # and the vertex will be printed in the recursive call, too.
            # visited.append(neighbor)
            # print(f"{neighbor} -> ", end='')
            self.DFS(neighbor, visited)
```

This assumes that your initial call will always be `DFS(root, None, visited)`. Which I think is a reasonable assumption.

On second thought, perhaps using the `visited` parameter as the condition is a better idea:

```
    if vertex is None:
        vertex = self.root

    if visited is None:
        visited = []
    else:
        # Not the first vertex, so need to add the separator.
        print(f" ->", end='')

    print(f"{vertex}", end='')
```

The whole point is that it's easier to special-case the first item than the last.